# Converting Darknet53 gives "nan" results in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolo, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to convert Yolo v3 to tensorflow 2.0 
I wrote the Darknet53 network layers and I am able to run it on both test inputs as well as actual images but the result in both cases is 'nan'

I already tried scaling the code up and down. First by dividing the image by 255 to scale between 0 and 1 as in the original paper and by multiplying by 255 to check if the values are too low to process. I also tried the original image without scaling.

Here is the actual network

```py
import tensorflow as tf 

class ResnetIdentityBlock(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size, filters):
        super(ResnetIdentityBlock, self).__init__(name='')
        filters1, filters2, filters3 = filters
        self.conv2a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters1, (1,1))
        self.bn2a = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.conv2b = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters2, kernel_size, padding="SAME")
        self.bn2b = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.conv2c = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters3, (1,1))
        self.bn2c = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
        x = self.conv2a(input_tensor)
        x = self.bn2a(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        print(f"after conv + bn a \n{x.shape}")
        x = self.conv2b(x)
        x = self.bn2b(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        print(f"after conv + bn b \n{x.shape}")
        x = self.conv2c(x)
        x = self.bn2c(x, training=training)
        print(f"after conv + bn c \n{x.shape}")
        x += input_tensor
        print(f"input shape\n {input_tensor.shape}")
        print(f"final shape \n{x.shape}")
        return tf.nn.relu(x)


class Darknet53Block(tf.keras.Model):
    '''the main block of Darknet53, two conv followed by a residual'''
    def __init__(self, filters):
        super(Darknet53Block, self).__init__(name='')
        self.conv2a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters,1)
        self.bn2a = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-05)

        self.conv2b = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters*2, 3, padding="SAME")
        self.bn2b = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-05)
    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
        x = self.conv2a(input_tensor)
        x = self.bn2a(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, 0.1)
        x = self.conv2b(x)
        x = self.bn2b(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, 0.1)
        x += input_tensor
        return x 

class Darknet53(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Darknet53, self).__init__(name='')

        self.bn = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-05)

        self.conv2a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2b = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2)
        self.dn_a = Darknet53Block(filters=32)

        self.conv2c = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=3,  strides=2)
        self.dn_b = Darknet53Block(filters=64)

        self.conv2d = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=2)
        self.dn_c = Darknet53Block(filters=128)

        self.conv2e = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=2)
        self.dn_d = Darknet53Block(filters=256)

        self.conv2f = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1024,kernel_size=3,  strides=2)
        self.dn_e = Darknet53Block(filters=512)

    def call(self, input_tensor):
        x = self.conv2a(input_tensor)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.1)
        x = self.conv2b(x)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.1)
        x = self.dn_a(x)
        x = self.conv2c(x)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.1)    
        for i in range(2):
            x = self.dn_b(x)
        x = self.conv2d(x)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.1)
        for i in range(8):
            x = self.dn_c(x)
        scale_1 = x 

        x = self.conv2e(x)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.1)
        for i in range(8):
            x = self.dn_d(x)
        scale_2 = x 

        x = self.conv2f(x)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.1)
        for i in range(4):
            x = self.dn_e(x)
        return scale_1, scale_2, x
```

and here is the test code

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":

    import numpy as np
    import cv2 

    darknet = Darknet53()

    img = cv2.imread("20190413_143522_126.jpg")
    img = cv2.resize(img, (416,416))/255.0
    img = img.reshape((1,416,416,3))
    img = np.asarray(img, dtype=np.float32)
    print(img)

    result1, result2, result3 = darknet(img)
    print(result1)
    print(result2)
    print(result3)
```

I expect the output to be between 0 and 1. The size of the results are fine but they all seem to be populated with 'nan'

Answer (score 2):

Since tensorflow 2.1.0rc0, which is soon to be released as the final 2.1.0, there is a new API specifically designed to help users find out the root cause of such numerical issues liek this, namely `tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics()`.

`tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics()` is the successor to the old API in TF1 called `tf.add_check_numerics_ops()`, which is not supported in TF2.

To use the new API in TF2, you just need to add the line to a place in your code before your model is built and run. As a simplistic example.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics()  # Add this line to your code.

#...
darknet = Darknet53()
result1, result2, result3 = darknet(img)
```

During the execution (i.e., the `darknet(img)`) call, the program will error out as soon as any ops (whether executed eagerly or inside a tf.function graph) outputs any infinity or NaN in their floating-type tensor outputs. The error message will tell you

- The name of the op
- The dtype and shape of the output tensor
- Whether -infinity, +infinity, NaN, or any combination of them exist in the output tensor
- The stack trace (line of code) that created the op originally, to help you locate the source of the problem. [See example screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrbwL.png)